# Does there exist any method that can be used to calculate or evaluate $A$ given $Ax=y$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a simple equation like as $Ax=y$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n},x\in\mathbb{R}^n,y\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Given that $x,y$ are known a prior, does there exist any method that can be used to calculate or evaluate $A$? ($A$ is not a sparse matrix)

Comment: $A$ is underdetermined, so there are many different matrices $A$ that satisfy this equation.  You can view $Ax = y$ as a linear system of equations where the unknowns are the entries of $A$.

Comment: You must know enough $x$ and $y$ correspondences to make a basis with the $x$ vectors. Then you can determine $A$.

Comment: Of course the answer should depend on what $m$ and $n$ are and the given $x$ and $y$. It could be that (1)no solution (2)one solution (3)infinitely many solutions. 

For instance, playing around with the dimensions a bit:

 - ($m=n=1$) $A[0]=[1]$ has no solution; $Ax=y$ has a unique solution when $x\neq 0$;
 - ($n=1$, $m>1$) $Ax=y$ if and only if the vector $y\in{\bf R}^m$ is a $x$-multiple of $A\in{\bf R}^m$;
 - ($m=1$, $n>1$) $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions: vectors orthogonal to $x$ in ${\bf R}^n$;
 - etc.

No silver bullet.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitelly many matrices $A$ which satisfy your condition. This is because $Ax=y$ is a system of $m$ linear equations, but $A$ has $m\times n$ variables. So no, you cannot calculate $A$ from $Ax=y$.

Answer (score 0):

We can generate an arbitrary number of matrices for which this equation is true.  To show this, let $G_n \in GL(n)$ be any invertible $n \times n$ matrix whose first column is the vector $x$;  this implies that
$$
G_n \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = x. 
$$
Similarly, let $G_m \in GL(m)$ be any invertible $m \times m$ matrix whose first column is $y$.  Putting these two equations together, we get
$$
A G_n \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = G_m \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
\underbrace{G_m^{-1} A G_n}_{\equiv B} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
This implies that the first column of the matrix $B = G_m^{-1} A G_n$ must be $[ 1 \: 0 \: 0 \dots 0 ]^T$, but its other $n - 1$ columns can be anything you like.

Thus, we can conclude that for *any* three matrices $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, G_m \in GL(m), G_n \in GL(n)$ such that:

- the first column of $G_n$ is $x$;
- the first column of $G_m$ is $y$; and
- the first column of $B$ is $[ 1 \: 0 \: 0 \dots 0 ]^T$,

the matrix $A = G_m B G_n^{-1}$ will satisfy the equations $Ax = y$.